# Keep legend item & feature count even when item does not appear in current Atlas feature

Tags: qgis, features, atlas

I would like to see all legend items  irrespective of whether the item appears in the current Atlas feature. I have formatted the legend such that count of each item appears in brackets, next to the item label in the legend. For items that do not appear in the current Atlas feature, I would like to see a zero in brackets, next to the item label in the legend.

I however would like the legend to reflect only information regarding the current Atlas Feature. For example: if for a given Atlas feature, there are 10 Physician offices, 7 Diagnostic Imaging Facilities, 0 Acute care Facilities, 0 Ambulatory care facilities, I would like the legend to look as follows:

- Physician Offices (10)
- Diagnostic Imaging Facility (7)
- Acute Care   Facility (0)
- Ambulatory Care Facility (0)